# Connect to remote docker host / deploy a stack

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-stack

I created a docker stack to deploy to a swarm. Now I´m a bit confused how the proper way looks like to deploy it to a real server?

Of course I can

1. `scp` my `docker-stack.yml` file to a node of my swarm
2. `ssh` into the node
3. run `docker stack deploy -c docker-stack.yml stackname`

So there is the `docker-machine` tool I thought.
I tried

```
docker-machine -d none --url=tcp://<RemoteHostIp>:2375 node1
```

what only seems to work if you open the port without TLS?
I received following:

```
$ docker-machine env node1
Error checking TLS connection: Error checking and/or regenerating the certs: There was an error validating certificates for host "192.168.178.49:2375": dial tcp 192.168.178.49:2375: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
You can attempt to regenerate them using 'docker-machine regenerate-certs [name]'.
Be advised that this will trigger a Docker daemon restart which might stop running containers.
```

I already tried to generate a certificate & copy it over to the host:

```
 ssh-keygen -t rsa
 ssh-copy-id myuser@node1
```

Then I ran

```
docker-machine --tls-ca-cert PathToMyCert --tls-client-cert PathToMyCert create -d none --url=tcp://192.168.178.49:2375 node1
```

With the following result:

```
 $ docker-machine env node1
 Error checking TLS connection: Error checking and/or regenerating the certs: There was an error validating certificates for host "node1:2375": There was an error reading certificate
 You can attempt to regenerate them using 'docker-machine regenerate-certs [name]'.
 Be advised that this will trigger a Docker daemon restart which might stop running containers.
```

I also tried it with the generic driver

```
$ docker-machine create -d generic --generic-ssh-port "22" --generic-ssh-user "MyRemoteUser" --generic-ip-address 192.168.178.49 node1
Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
(node1) No SSH key specified. Assuming an existing key at the default    location.
Waiting for machine to be running, this may take a few minutes...
Detecting operating system of created instance...
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Detecting the provisioner...
Error creating machine: Error detecting OS: OS type not recognized
```

How do I add the remote docker host with docker-machine properly with TLS?
Or is there a better way to deploy stacks to a server/into production?

I read often that you shouldn´t expose the docker port but not once how to do it. And I can´t believe that they doesn´t provide a simple way to do this.

**Update & Solution**

I think both answers have there qualification.
I found [Deploy to Azure Offical Doc](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-azure/deploy/#connecting-to-your-manager-nodes-using-ssh) (it´s the same for AWS). 
The answer from @Tarun Lalwani pointed me into the right direction and it´s almost the official solution. Thats the reason I accepted his answer.

For me the following commands worked:

```
ssh -fNL localhost:2374:/var/run/docker.sock myuser@node1
```

Then you can run either:

```
docker -H localhost:2374 stack deploy -c stack-compose.yml stackname
```

or

```
DOCKER_HOST=localhost:2374
docker stack deploy -c stack-compose.yml stackname
```

The answer from @BMitch is also valid and the security concern he mentioned shouldn´t be ignored.

**Update 2**

The answer from @bretf is a awesome way to connect to your swarm. Especially if you have more than one. It´s still beta but works for swarms which are available to the internet and don´t have a ARM architecture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would prefer not opening/exposing the docker port even if I am thinking of TLS. I would rather use a SSH tunnel and then do the deployment

```
ssh -L 2375:127.0.0.1:2375 myuser@node1
```

And then use

```
DOCKER_HOST=tcp://127.0.0.1:2375
docker stack deploy -c docker-stack.yml stackname
```

Comment: The commands don´t work but they pointed me to the right direction. I found [Docker Doku](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-azure/deploy/#connecting-to-your-manager-nodes-using-ssh). For me worked: `ssh -p 22 -fNL localhost:2374:/var/run/docker.sock myuser@node1` with `docker -H localhost:2374 ps` or setting `DOCKER_HOST`

Comment: When you tried setting the 2375 port, I assumed that you have already exposed `127.0.0.1:2375` in your docker daemon settings. Since you had not done that already you had to map the traffic to the socket instead

Comment: Thanks @pr177 for the `-f` option...I wasn't aware of that. I've been banging my head trying to get an ampersand into my YAML file (on the end of the command, so that it runs in the background), and the `-f` made the whole setup much easier.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need docker-machine for this. Docker has the detailed steps to configure TLS [in their documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/). The steps involve:

- creating a CA
- create and sign a server certificate
- configuring the dockerd daemon to use this cert and validate client certs
- create and sign a client certificate
- copy the ca and client certificate files to your client machine's .docker folder
- set some environment variables to use the client certificates and remote docker host

I wouldn't use the ssh tunnel method on a multi-user environment since any user with access to 127.0.0.1 would have root access to the remote docker host without a password or any auditing.

Comment: Thank your for your answer I will go with the offical solution, but I will spend some time to get more information about the concerns you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Docker for Windows or Docker for Mac, [Docker Cloud](https://cloud.docker.com) has a more automated way to setup your TLS certs and get you securely connected to a remote host for free. Under "Swarms" there's "Bring your own Swarm" which runs an agent container on your Swarm managers to let you easily use your local docker cli without manual cert setup. It still requires the Swarm port open to internet, but this setup ensures it has TLS mutual auth enabled.

[Here's a youtube video showing how to set it up](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VJmbCioYKGg). It can also support group permissions for adding/removing other admins from remotely accessing the Swarm.

Comment: Oh, I saw the AWS & Azure deployments in docker cloud but not the "Bring your own swarm". Thank your for that! I think thats an awesome way if you have no problem with docker cloud and to open the swarm port to the internet.